# jQuery select list element not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select the first list item li in the ul#suckerfishnav in the main navigation here: http://fluroltd.com/clients/harveys/. Using

```
$('ul#suckerfishnav').find('li').slice(0,1) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

My aim is to add a class="first" to the first li in the list.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s94S7/ what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul#suckerfishnav li:first-child').addClass("first");
```

I've [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s94S7/1/) to show it working

Answer (score 0):

You could just use plain CSS for this too:

```
#suckerfishnav li:first-child {background-color:Red;);
```

Comment: assuming it's supported in the browsers of choice

Comment: If you look back at his question he want's to add the class of `first`, I guess he's using bg=red just to show the selector working. Also first-child is not support by all browsers, especially older ones.

Comment: who uses these 'older' browsers anyway, they should be shot!
:)
Okay, fair point, I was just suggesting CSS may (or may not) be an easier way to do it.